# "Old style JOIN (ANSI JOINs) syntax" error in a simple query without subqueries and joins

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio

Validating the following query:

```
SELECT 
    GetDate() as Valid_From,
    'Lorem Ipsum' as Filler
FROM 
    SampleSourceDE
```

shows this error:

> An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: Old style
>   JOIN (ANSI JOINs) syntax is not allowed. Please use standard syntax. ,
>   is not a known data extension or system data view. You can only query
>   existing data extensions or system data views.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQL validation in Marketing Cloud does have a strange quirk that it seems to treat underscores (`_`) near the `From` string as spaces - this causes the query to interpret the `From` part of `Valid_From` as the command that's responsible for the source of Data.

Since it's not the last column selected, the system tries to look for a data extension named `,`.

To confirm this, just reverse the order of desired columns to:

```
SELECT 
    'Lorem Ipsum' as Filler,
    GetDate() as Valid_From
FROM 
    SampleSourceDE
```

The error will now be:

> Errors: FROM is not a known data extension or system data view. You
>   can only query existing data extensions or system data views.

The following names will not pass validation when selected without square brackets:

- `Valid_From_Date` - _Date will be treated as a source
- `From_Date` - _Date will be treated as a source
- `Valid_From` - as described above the very next string will be interpreted as the source (either `,` or `FROM`)
- `Valid_____From` - same as above, it doesn't matter how many underscores you have

---

**Solutions**:

1. Wrap `Valid_From` in square brackets. This query will pass validation:

> ```
> SELECT 
>     GetDate() as [Valid_From],
>     'Lorem Ipsum' as Filler
> FROM 
>     SampleSourceDE
> ```

2. Change the column name, so that there's no standalone `From` string fragment surrounded by underscores, for example `ValidationFromDate` or `Valid_FromDate` *<sub>(if you're a monster)</sub>*

Comment: I just had to comment that this was a well explained and thorough answer! Thanks so much for sharing.